# Python version update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I updated the python version on my Dell machine from 2.7.15 to 3.6.5, but after typing python -V I noticed that python is still at version 2.7.15

Here are the lines of code:

```
remus@remus-Inspiron-5559:~$ sudo apt install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.6.5-3).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
remus@remus-Inspiron-5559:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.15rc1
remus@remus-Inspiron-5559:~$
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Try running `python3 -V`. Basically you have multiple versions installed because there are various system scripts that rely on the older version. Cross site dupe: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3

Answer (score 1):

You will always keep Python v2 (the `python` command and the `python-` packages) alongside with Python v3 (the `python3` command and the `python3-*` packages). There are many things on your system that have been written for V2 and wouldn't work with V3, so you cannot get rid of V2 (but nothing forces you to use V2 for your own scripts).